# Round off percentages in scala and total should match 100

Tags: scala, rounding

I have a scala sequence of tuples like below

```
seqOfTuples: List[(String, Double)] = List((a,25.52), (a,25.54), (a,48.94), (b,25.52), (b,25.54), (b,48.94))
```

I am trying to round off the second value in those tuples to a single decimal and equate them to a sum of 100 (by adding the balance fraction to the last number) for any given first value.

```
result: List[(String, AnyVal)] = List((a,25.5), (a,25.5), (a,49), (b,25.5), (b,25.5), (b,49))
```

What I have tried so far is to round off but the results won't equate to a sum of 100.

```
scala> val partialResult = seqOfTuples.map (x => (x._1, BigDecimal(x._2).setScale(1, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble))
partialResult: List[(String, Double)] = List((a,25.5), (a,25.5), (a,48.9), (b,25.5), (b,25.5), (b,48.9))
```

How can I do that?

Comment: do you mean a sum by unique tuple._1 should be equal to 100? Such that, for `a` it should be: 25.5 + 25.5 + 48.9 = 100, but it is actually 99.9 ?

Comment: @AlexeyNovakov yes. Exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your `partialResult` (abbreviated to `pr` below), you could subtract the `Double` values from `100.0` until you get uncomfortably close to zero, at which point you ignore the received `Double` and recalculate its "true" value.

```
pr.foldLeft((Map.empty[String,Double].withDefaultValue(100.0)
            ,List.empty[(String,Double)])){ case ((m,res),(str,dbl)) =>
    if (math.abs(m(str) - dbl) < 1.1)  //too close
      (m, (str,m(str))::res)           //use remainder
    else
      (m + (str -> (m(str)-dbl)), (str,dbl)::res)  //update Map, build result
}._2.reverse
//res0: List[(String, Double)] = List((a,25.5), (a,25.5), (a,49.0)
//                                  , (b,25.5), (b,25.5), (b,49.0))
```